# Changing div time

Tags: javascript

```
  <style>
    #main div {
      display: none;
    }
  </style>

  <div id="main">
    <div>first</div>
    <div>second</div>
    <div>third</div>
  </div>

  <script>
    var divElems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#main div')),
        main = document.querySelector('#main'), i = 0;


    setInterval(function f() {
      var item = divElems[i % divElems.length];
      item.style.display = 'block';
      i++;
    }, 3000);
  </script>
```

Can you please tell how to make  within #main show up on the queue without stopping? Initially, they are hidden.

Element first, second and third should appear in sequence, every 3 seconds

```
First shows a block
<div>first</div>
then instead
<div>second</div>
and then
<div>third</div>
```

Comment: Can you explain to us what it should be in comparison to this: http://jsfiddle.net/b2aaku11/ ?

Comment: element first, second and third should appear in sequence, every 3 seconds

First shows a block
`<div> first </ div>
then instead
<div> second </ div>
and then
<div> third </ div>`

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov It already does that though.

Comment: So you want this order: `first` -> `third` -> `second`, correct? What order would you want it if you added `fourth` and `fifth` to the mix? Should this be scalable or always 3 dividers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have updated my answer again after your comment. [Is this what you are looking for?](https://jsfiddle.net/k7eb8275/1/)

```
var divElems = [].slice.call(document.querySelectorAll('#main div')),
main = document.querySelector('#main'),
i = 0;

divElems[0].style.display = 'block';

setInterval(function f() {
    var item = divElems[i % divElems.length];
    item.style.display = 'none';
    i++;
    item = divElems[i % divElems.length];
    item.style.display = 'block';
}, 3000);
```

Comment: You do not understand the question. We need to show the first block, then instead of the second, and then, instead of the second - third.

Comment: @AleksandrAleksandrov Updated my answers. Is this what you are looking for?